# C# Send NAudio WaveOut to Bing Speech Recognition Platform

Tags: speech-recognition, naudio, bing, speech

I am able to record audio from the microphone with the following code:

```
private void buttonBeginToSpeak_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WaveIn wi;
    WaveOut wo;
    private BufferedWaveProvider bwp;

    wo = new WaveOut();
    wi = new WaveIn();
    wi.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(wi_DataAvailable);

    bwp = new BufferedWaveProvider(wi.WaveFormat);
    bwp.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;
    wo.Init(bwp);
    wi.StartRecording();
}

private void buttonFinishSpeaking_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wi.StopRecording();
    wo.Play(); // this sentence plays the audio previously recorded
}

void wi_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    bwp.AddSamples(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
}
```

How can I send this audio (not through a file, directly) to the Bing Speech Recognition Service

Answer (score 0):

The [new speech service SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/)  will support audio stream very soon. Please stay tuned.